# Python/Django remove text in variable

Tags: python, django, text, replace

at my views.py i have the following line

```
encrypted_token_message = encryption_key.encrypt(PGPMessage.new(token_message), cipher=SymmetricKeyAlgorithm.AES256)
```

which creates a PGP message with a version information like this

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> Version: XYZ

How can i remove/replace this version line?

if i try:

```
encrypted_token_message_pretty = (encrypted_token_message.replace('Version: XYZ', 'Version: XXX'))
```

i get back:

```
'PGPMessage' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Because it's an object not a string itself you can call specific attribute of `encrypted_token_message_pretty` and then perform replace operation on it.

Comment: Well cool, thanks for this hint. can you provide an example or an answere here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [PGPy documentation](https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest), the `encrypt` method returns an instance of `PGPMessage`. The reason why you can convert that object into a `str` is because it overrides the special `__str__` method.

Anyway, `replace` is a method of `str`, not of `PGPMessage`. So if you want to replace the `Version:`, convert your message to a string, and then replace the version.

```py
encrypted_token = str(encryption_key.encrypt(PGPMessage.new(token_message), cipher=SymmetricKeyAlgorithm.AES256))  # Gets the string representing the newly created message
encrypted_token_message_pretty = encrypted_token.replace('Version: XYZ', 'Version: XXX')  # encrypted_token is now a string, you can replace whatever you want
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, i was a bit confused about the object handling here.

Answer (score 1):

It's and object not a string itself. You can call a specific attribute on it in order to replace the version number like this -

`encrypted_token_message_pretty._attribute_name.replace('Version: XYZ', 'Version: XXX')`

You can also find the list of possible attributes using `encrypted_token_message_pretty.__dict__`